# how to order multiple FROM?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, g++, alpine-linux

I have issue ordering multiple FROM in Dockerfile. I'd like to use both bash utils, e.g. bc in shell scripts, and g++.

First attempt:

```
FROM gcc:7.4

FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk add --no-cache bash gawk sed grep bc coreutils

RUN g++ ...
```

gives

```
---> Running in ...
/bin/sh: g++: not found
```

Second attempt:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk add --no-cache bash gawk sed grep bc coreutils

FROM gcc:7.4

RUN g++ ...
```

now gives

```
/test/test.sh: line 3: bc: command not found
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how it works. Multiple `FROM` directives allows you to create [multistage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) `Dockerfile`. All stages are isolated and executed sequentially. It is possible to access files from one stage in the other one, but in order to do that files have to be copied into the corresponding stage, but I'm not going to cover it here.

In your case, however, you don't need to use multistage build, just install `gcc` as a package similar to other packages:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk add --no-cache bash gawk sed grep bc coreutils g++

RUN g++ ...
```

You could also create virtual package in order to remove any build packages when you are done with it. Example below removes `gcc` after it has been used:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk add --no-cache bash gawk sed grep bc coreutils \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies g++ \
    && g++ ... \
    && apk del build-dependencies
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped a lot. I just had to add g++ instead of gcc. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! Can you please accept answer if it was helpful.